# TalkBack does not announce webview content inside an iframe

Tags: android, cordova, iframe, android-webview, accessibility

I have a PhoneGap app that displays content in an iframe via PhoneGap's webview.  When TalkBack is turned on, TalkBack will not announce anything inside the iframe.

I've created a test app with the following main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Test paragraph</p>
    <iframe src="content.html">
      You can't get there from here.
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

The iframe content is:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Iframe Content</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Iframe content</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I tap `Test paragraph` Talkback will announce it, but when I tap anywhere inside the iframe, Talkback highlights the entire iframe and does not announce anything.

If I try the same main page and iframe content in the system browser, TalkBack does announce the `Iframe content` paragraph inside the iframe when I tap on it.

Is there something I need to do to get TalkBack to announce content inside an iframe in PhoneGap?

Comment: On what version of Android are you testing this?

Comment: So far, I've tested on devices running 4.4.4, 4.3, 4.2.2, and 4.1.2.  All behave the same way.